# After user changed password, how long does ADAL's cached access token expired for iOS

Tags: ios, azure, adal

I encountered a weird problem.

I have no problem logging into ADAL

WITH

```
authContext.acquireTokenWithResource(resourceUrl, clientId: clientId, redirectUri: redirectUri, promptBehavior: AD_PROMPT_ALWAYS, userId: nil, extraQueryParameters: "nux=1&login_hint=desmondkoh@")
```

AND

```
authContext.acquireTokenSilentWithResource(resourceUrl, clientId: clientId, redirectUri: redirectUri)
```

BUT

say if a user changed their password, I can still log into via `acquireTokenSilentWithResource`

so my question is 
How long does access token in cache expire for iOS when a user changed the password?

cheers

Des

Comment: An AAD token needs to be refreshed every hour; so I would say wait an hour after changing your password and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can take up to an hour for a password change to force a user to re-authenticate in a particular application.

A password change does not invalidate any access tokens.  All the access tokens have a specific expiry time, usually one hour for AAD tokens, and they will remain valid until that expiry time has been reached.  Once the access token expires the next acquireToken request will cause ADAL to attempt to exchange the refresh token for a new access token at AAD.  It is at this time that a failure can occur if the user has changed their password.  The AAD service will notice that the user associated with the refresh token as changed their password and reject the request to silently acquire a new access token.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Indeed the AAD Tokens will expire after that.